# Is partition created by dd (and cached) instantly available for writing

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, cache

I'm creating a partition (from backup) with dd and need to know if there is a need of some sort of sync/timeout before I can access it.
As I know data may be cached in dirty pages. But what if I read/write a file or device that has some part of its data in cache. Will I get/overwrite most recent data (from cache) or only data that has been flushed.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be pleased to hear that none of that is relevant. You (presumably) restored via `/dev/sdb1`. That same device is what you're going to mount, so it sees the same content that you wrote.

What wouldn't work is restoring the partition table by writing to `/dev/sdb` and expecting `/dev/sdb1` (say) to magically spring into existence. For that you'd need to run something like `partprobe /dev/sdb`